# Is it known if $\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^3}\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta

> Is it known if $\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^3}\in\mathbb{Q}$?

It is obvious that $\frac{\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}}\in\mathbb{Q}$, but since there is no closed form for the odd values, are we left to be unable to determine if the solution could have such a form?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60595/is-zeta3-pi3-rational

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure it is that "obvious" that $\frac{\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}}\in\mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: @fretty Did you look at the general solution to $\zeta(2n)$?  Every component with the exception of the $\pi^{2n}$ is rational, and multiplied and divided together, ${\mathbb{Q}\over\mathbb{Q}}\in\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: But the formula itself is hardly obvious...

Comment: @fretty Well, it was rather obvious when I looked at it.  What gave you doubts?

Comment: The formula is non-trivial...sure once you KNOW it then it is obvious that $\frac{\zeta(2k)}{\pi^{2k}}\in\mathbb{Q}$ but the formula itself isn't obvious, it requires some non-trivial maths to find/prove it!

Comment: It's only obvious ONCE you know the formula. It isn't obvious just from the definition of the zeta function.

Comment: @fretty Oh, of course not.  When you said formula, I didn't think you meant the definition.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Well $\zeta(3)$ is what known as Apery's constant, and it is proved to be irrational. But whether $\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^3}$ is rational or not is not known. For little more info you can check [this link](http://gonitsora.com/aperys-constant/)